# PHP delay of 1 second on every script on localhost on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, apache

Every PHP script takes at least one second to display in the browser when run on localhost. Why is this happening?

If I have a file say test.html that has the word TEST in it and file test.php that has the word TEST in it (without any PHP tags, identical files just different extensions), the PHP file takes one second to execute and display in the browser while the HTML file loads instantly.

I have a Phenom II X6 @ 3.2GHz, CPU utilization is near 20% on one core at lowest voltage when any (even empty) PHP file is called. There is no noticable HDD activity. According to phpinfo() Server API is CGI/FastCGI

Comment: This never happened on previous installations of Windows

Comment: any code vailable? maybe its a coding issue?

Comment: nothing in the code, no PHP tags, just one word so that it displays something

Comment: What web server? Could it be that the php interpreter isn't persistent, but has to be loaded for every request?

Comment: Eyeballed it. :) When I test with microtime it returns 0ms

Comment: It's Apache 2.2.17 and PHP is 5.3.5         How do I find out if it's persistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using PHP as an Apache module rather than CGI.
I had to revert to PHP 5.2 because 5.3 something something blah blah won't work with Apache 2 because of Visual C 9 or something. Whatever, works great now